# Write to a masked array in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have an array `x` and a mask for the array `mask`. I want to use `np.copyto` to write to `x` using `mask`. Is there a way I can do this? Just trying to use `copyto` doesn't work, I suppose because the masked `x` is not writeable.

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
mask = np.array([False,False,True,True])

np.copyto(x[mask],[30,40])

x
# array([1, 2, 3, 4])
# Should be array([1, 2, 30, 40])
```

Comment: Won't `x[mask] = [30,40]` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented index assignment works

```
In [16]: x[mask]=[30,40]

In [17]: x
Out[17]: array([ 1,  2, 30, 40])
```

You have to careful when using `x[mask]`.  That is 'advanced indexing', so it creates a copy, not a view of `x`.  With direct assignment that isn't an issue, but with copyto `x[mask]` is passed as an argument to the function.

```
In [19]: y=x[mask]
In [21]: np.copyto(y,[2,3])
```

changes `y`, but not `x`.

Checking its docs I see the `copyto` does accept a `where` parameter, which could be used as

```
In [24]: np.copyto(x,[0,0,31,41],where=mask)

In [25]: x
Out[25]: array([ 1,  2, 31, 41])
```